# How to dual boot ubuntu 13.10 with windows 8 (non UEFI)

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2

I just want to ask..

How to dual boot ubuntu 13.10 x64 with windows 8 x64 (non UEFI installation)? And can I use default windows 8 grub? Because I like it so much.

Just search for the answer (almost) anywhere but find no answer.

I am using ASUS A46CB with Core i3 processor.

Thank you for your help.. :)

P.S. : I have 3 primary partition (that detected in windows 8 explorer) with MBR partition style

Answer (score 1):

- First install Ubuntu 13.10 in a Primary partition or Extended partition as your wish.
- Then boot up the windows live disk and install windows 8 in another primary partition.
- After the windows 8 installation completed,re bootup the windows 8 live usb/cd and click on the `System Repair` option.Then select the command prompt option and run the following commands on it.

  ```
  bootrec /fixmbr
  bootrec /fixboot
  bootrec /rebuildbcd
  ```
- Then reboot your pc,now you can select windows 8 or ubuntu from the windows grub.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you wouldn't be able to dual-boot them. To answer your second question though, by default you have to use the bootloader (GRUB) that comes with Linux, as the Windows bootloader won't recognize the linux distribution.  There have been posts online about configuring the Windows bootloader with the information to boot a Linux distro, but I'm not sure how relevant they are to Windows 8.

As for your three primary partitions, I would venture that one is the boot partition for Windows 8 (as Windows 7 used that type of setup), and one is probably the recovery partition for your computer. So, you'll want to resize the main data partition (C:). Ubuntu *Should* do this for you, if you run the installation from a Live CD.